# Pass specific Core Data through protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, nsmanagedobject

I am using protocols and delegates to send information from my **View Controller** to my **Custom View Controller**.

**ViewController.swift ==**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIAlertViewDelegate, StartAlertViewVCDelegate {

func requiredText() -> String { return "test123" }
```

**CustomViewController.swift ==**

```
@objc protocol StartAlertViewVCDelegate {
func requiredText() -> String }
```

&

```
func requiredText(info: NSString) { println(info) }
```

This works fine and dandy, but my problem is that I actually need to send an item from Core Data. This item is selected from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.. EX:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    println("***** Row \(indexPath.row) selected *****")

    var infoData = [NSManagedObject]()
    let company = infoData[indexPath.row]
    company.valueForKey("openDoor") as String?

    self.selectedOpenDoor = company.valueForKey("openDoor") as String!
```

I need to pass the selectedOpenDoor string to my Custom View Controller.
But when I run the application, the compiler grabs selectedDoorOpen before anything has been put in the string (it runs at startup)

Is there anyway to pass the delegate after didSelectRow is fired?

Any suggestions?

Comment: `var infoData = [NSManagedObject]()` creates an *empty* array.

Comment: I eventually fill the array.